# Could be a problem if I used a little bit different oil filter for my car?

Tags: oil-change, oil-filter

I have an Opel Astra H Caravan 2008 1.7 CDTI 81kW (type 0035/AHO). I recently changed the oil, but I'm not sure if I used the right oil filter. I purchased two of them:

1. [one from amazon](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00B8YAX6I/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)
2. [one from ebay](https://www.ebay.de/itm/%C3%96lfilter-Opel-Astra-G-H-J-Corsa-C-D-Combo-Zafira-B-Mokka-Meriva-B-1-7-CDTI-DTI/182112305421?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649)

This type of filter was in the car before:
[image: This type of filter was in the car before]

This is what ebay recommends:
[image: This is what ebay recommends]

In the car was the first one (from amazon), this is why I choose to replace it with the same type. Ebay however says, that this is not the right type for this engine. The first one has a rubber gasket on both sides. The measurements, though, are the same.

I am a little bit worried. Should I replace it rather with the first one?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! :) I would say that as long as it fits snugly and the filter material is comparable, then it should be fine. **BUT** I'm not at all familiar with your vehicle, so I'm leaving this as a comment in hopes that someone with more knowledge of your exact vehicle has a better answer. I do know that for my motorcycle, there are ~20 different filters I can use, but they are all pretty similar. A few of them are larger and would require a little more oil to be added to the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first type surely fits (I own the same car with the same engine).

The second one *could* fit, I do not know. But I would definitely not use it since the oil circuit is a delicate one, you do not want unexpected things happen there so an design that deviates from the OEM one is a big no-go for me

Comment: so, you say, the first one is the OEM and the second is just some non original copy?

Comment: the first is similar to the OEM design, the second isn't

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on the ebay compatibility tool. To be honest its useless and not fit for purpose when it comes to parts that could have multiple options such as filters, radiators etc.

If in doubt message the seller the registration or vin number or use a motor factors / parts store with a proper manufacture look up system (most if not all will have one)

To answer your question though, yes the first one is correct. I know as I have worked with many Opel 1.7/9 diesels.